# How to send TestNG report within the email notification from Teamcity?

Tags: testng, teamcity-9.0

I am in the process of migrating my projects to Teamcity from another CI server. Sending out email notification with the TestNG reports as email body was really easy in the earlier one as I just has to use a plugin and provide a path to the report file in email body.

I have already generated the artifacts and can see the reports on Teamcity server per build but also need to send these out to people who dont have access to Teamcity server, therefore these need to be a part of email notifications.

Is it possible to achieve this on per build configuration in Teamcity?

Comment: Havent found anything on this yet. Planning on creating an app only to send email and discontinuing Teamcity email notification.

Comment: `<p>Build artifacts:</p>
  <#list build.artifactsDirectory.listFiles() as file>
    <a href="${webLinks.getDownloadArtefactUrl(build.buildTypeExternalId, build.buildId, file.name)}">${file.name}</a> (${file.length()}B)<br/>
  </#list>`

Will list all artifcats with their name in the email. Problem is, internally these are all Hyperlink. Better than before but still unable to share this with people who don't have access to TC server.

Answer (score 0):

Currently  ( TC version 10.x) there is no way to attach an artifact in Teamcity Email notification. We can only provide link to the artifact.

I have implemented a separate build step itself that takes the artifact and then sends email. This can be easily done using a simple Java send email project.